# Sort Stickies by desktop

Tags: macos, applescript, sort

I have OS X Lion 10.7.5 with four desktops and also have 4 groups of stickies (one group per desktop). Every time that I have to reopen the Stickies app, they are unsorted (all stickies open on the same desktop). Does anybody knows if there is a way, e.g., using AppleScript, to sort them?